# Android dialog box populate from Database

Tags: android

I want to get list of items inside my dialog box form database. 
I have "mylist" that is on Mainactivity. When I click one list item, I want the lists of 
items inside dialogbox.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

     ArrayList<String> getdialoglist = new ArrayList<String>();
     final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getdialoglist);

    ListView dialoglist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dialogListView);
    dialoglist.setAdapter(adapter1);

    String[] sColumns = {"_id", "title","description","date","location","trainer_id"};
    final Cursor cursor = db.query("training", sColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

    mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                int position, long _id) {
            builder.setTitle("Title");
            builder.setCursor(cursor, null, null);
            builder.setAdapter(adapter1, null);
            builder.create();
            builder.show();

        }

    });
```

Comment: Or is it possible to use the cursor of my list to display each single row in list. It yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fetch the list of Items from the pre-populated database and onItemClick appears dialogbox with more information about the items. Hope it might help you :)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private ListView trainingListView;  
    private ListAdapter trainingListAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Training> trainingArrayList;

    //Lists that contain title of trainings
    ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();

    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    //private static final String DB_PATH = "data/data/com.Areva.areva_attendance/databases/";
    final Context context = this;
    // Database Name
    //private static String DB_NAME = "attendance.sqlite";
    private Dialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        trainingListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.traininglistView);

        trainingArrayList = new ArrayList<Training>();

        // Create a list that contains only title of the training
        trainingListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getTrainingsList());

        trainingListView.setAdapter(trainingListAdapter);

        trainingListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long id) {

                // arg2 = the id of the item in our view (List/Grid) that we clicked
                // arg3 = the id of the item that we have clicked
                final Training data = trainingArrayList.get(arg2);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on position : " + arg2 + " and ID : " + id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);


                dialog.setTitle(data.getTitle());

                TextView description = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                description.setText("Description: "+ data.getDescription());

                TextView date = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                date.setText("Date: "+ data.getDate());

                TextView location = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                location.setText("Location: "+ data.getLocation());

                Button back_btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                back_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });

                Button start_btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button2);
                start_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TraineeActivity.class);
                        //intent.putExtra("data",trainingListView.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        intent.putExtra("trainingId", Training.getId());
                        intent.putExtra("title", data.getTitle().toString());
                        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                 dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private ArrayList<String> getTrainingsList() {

        //Open database helper Class
        DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        // Then we need to get a readable database
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

        //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT t.* FROM training t JOIN attendance a ON t._id=a.training_id=?;",
                // new String[] {Integer.toString(training_id)});
        final String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM training";

        //Getting a cursor to fetch data from the database
        final Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            Training training = new Training();
            training.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_ID)));
            training.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_TITLE)));
            training.setDescription (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_DESCRIPTION)));
            training.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_DATE)));
            training.setLocation(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_LOCATION)));
            //String Trainer_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_TRAINER_ID));


            //Pass to the arraylist
            trainingArrayList.add(training);

            // But we need a List of String to display in the ListView also.
            //That is why we create "titleList"
            titleList.add(training.getTitle());
        }
        return titleList;   
    }


}
```